# Using edit button in navigation bar for a sub table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Hi I have a `tableView` inside my view. But I want the edit in the navigation bar to work for the tableView. Could you please tell me how to do this?

I have the navigation bar set up for the main view and have the `tableView` set up as well.

I made a create navigation bar method:

```
- (UINavigationBar *)createNavigationBar
{
UINavigationItem *title = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Task Manager"];
UINavigationBar *new = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:nil];
title.leftBarButtonItem = addButton;
[new pushNavigationItem:title animated:YES];
UIColor *color = UIColorFromRGB(0xff8c00); // Dark orange
new.tintColor = color;
return new;
}
```

I have the

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

set up as well.

I basically need the red circles to appear for the sub-tableView when i tap the edit button in main navigation bar.

I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. Please ask me if you need any clarification.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a BOOL variable to store the current editing state and a function (`addTarget`) to the edit button which will put the table in edit mode based on this variable, like this :

```
-(IBAction) editWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    editMode = ! editMode;

    if(editMode) 
    {
        [table setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [table setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

You should rename that variable named `new` to something else !

Answer (score 0):

you just need to make your tableView to be in the edit mode .. you can do it like this

```
[yourTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

you will put this code in your button action .. so you need to change your code to be like this

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editPressed)];
```

Answer (score 0):

make this line in your *viewWillApear:* ...

```
[super setEditing:NO animated:yes];
```

then in your *editWasPressed:* method...

```
[my_table setEditing:!my_table.editing animated:YES];
```

Hope this will help you.....